# Static Methods in Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

Suppose I have a class in Java like this:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public void initialize(String id, Double num, String data){
       ....
   }

}
```

What is the ideal method type for my ClassicSingleton if I will be accessing an "instance" of it in another class?

Should initialize be a static function so that I can just call this in other class:

```
ClassicSingleton mySingleton = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
mySingleton = ClassicSingleton.initialize("id",0.0,"data");
```

or should I leave initialize as it is and call:

```
ClassicSingleton mySingleton = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
mySingleton.initialize("id",0.0,"data");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing instance then use the second option

```
ClassicSingleton mySingleton = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
mySingleton.initialize("id", 0.0, "data");
```

Answer (score 0):

`initialize` should be a static method. The idea of a Singleton is that it is the *only* instance of that object. If one object is initialized twice, or is initialized through an instance of that object, it slightly defeats the purpose of the Singleton pattern.

Personally, I like to call `initialize` in the constructor, which itself is only called once, to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the instance of Singleton class then you should go for the second one